# Problems with the c++ library SFML (#include)

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm having trouble with the c++ library SFML
I'm trying to make a simple and portable game for fun and as a challenge.
I've decided to use SFML as it looks easy.

The problem is that every time I try to link the library I get a linking error. No mater where the files are located it always dosen't work. So I thought it was some Visual Studio error. So my instinct decited to switch to a dev c++ project. That didn't work either. I followed many tutorials looked at many forms for nothing to work. By the way i did the EXACTLY same thing in Visual Studio as in Dev C++ so i will not be showing screenshots of VS 2022

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"




/*int WinMain(
HINSTANCE hInstance,
HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine,
int nShowCmd
)
{
    
}*/

//For Debbuining. The one above is for release
int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200,200), "SFML Works!");

    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);

    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    

    while(window.isOpen()){

        sf::Event event;

            while(window.pollEvent(event)){

                if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)

                window.close();

            }

    

    window.clear();

    window.draw(shape);

    window.display();

    

    }

}
```

#### SCREENSHOTS

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZOhP.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzB0S.png)

[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgvVu.png)

[screenshot4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgWzS.png)

[screenshot5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsfqW.png)

[screenshot6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mCaj.png)

I was expecting a window to pop up and show a green circle.

Comment: When you see _"some Visual Studio bs"_ - it's also important to communicate _exactly_ what that bs is. Don't have us guessing.

Comment: For Visual Studio you would need to use totally different binaries and your linker settings would be the library file names with a `.lib` extension. For Dev C++ you are probably using MinGW and want library files generated with MingW and they will likely have a `.a` or `.so` extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html).

First, [install vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html) and then sfml(vcpkg install sfml).

You can use sfml in visual studio.

By the way, you need to comment out `#include <Windows.h>`.

After set up you can use `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>`, too.

Comment: Thank you! I have a package manager for my new projects and i won't have any problems with the linker!